# Qt: using enums with QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I have a set of parameters that I need to edit, some of which are enums.

As of today, I use the raw value of the enum in a QSpinBox, which is not friendly at all. You have to remember the values by yourself and set the good one:

[image: my parameter editor]

For instance, E_Range could be presenting a combobox with these:

```
typedef enum {
    ERANGE_2_5  = 0, /*!< +/- 2.5 V */
    ERANGE_5    = 1, /*!< +/- 5 V */
    ERANGE_10   = 2, /*!< +/- 10 V */
    ERANGE_AUTO = 3  /*!< Auto range */
} TVoltageRange_e;
```

I didn't find anything about using an enum in a QComboBox. Is it possible?
If yes, what are the steps?

I mean, I guess I'll have to declare the enum through Qt so that it is "enumerable" with the Qt metaobject. But from there, I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you try this?
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49122-Joining-together-a-QComboBox-QStringList-and-enum

Comment: I stumbled on this but wasn't satisfied with the method: I think it's way too specific. I'd like to have generic components.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can always hardcode the values, but as soon as you modify that enum you have to rememeber to change the code that populates your combobox.

> I mean, I guess I'll have to declare the enum through Qt so that it is "enumerable" with the Qt metaobject. But from there, I'm not sure.

Exactly, using introspection is a smart move. Mark the enum with `Q_ENUMS` and add the `Q_OBJECT` macro. Then:

- Grab your class' metaobject via `Class::staticMetaObject()`
- Get the `QMetaEnum` for your enum via `QMetaObject::indexOfEnumerator()` + `QMetaObject::enumerator()`
- Get the number of keys via `QMetaEnum::keyCount()`, and iterate getting the key names and their corresponding values (`QMetaEnum::key()`, `QMetaEnum::keyToValue()`).

With this you'll be able to populate your combobox programmatically (the typical pattern is to add the enum key as the user-visible string and the corresponding value as its "item data", cf. `QComboBox`'s documentation.)

Comment: I'm surprised Qt doesn't include this as a standard method of QComboBox?!

Comment: Because it's easy to do, and quite too specific to truly be general purpose. But I encourage you to go ahead and [submit a patch](http://qt-project.org/contribute), then convince me that it's worth it :-)

Comment: In case anyone, like me, has doubts on how to use metaobject's, there is a nice tutorial on how to convert a enum value to Qstring [here](https://srikanthsombhatla.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/convert-enum-to-qstring/)

Answer (score 9):

An other way, using a **QMap** :

Declare and fill a `QMap<QString, QSomeObject::SomeEnum>` with the enum values you want in your combo box, then fill your QComboBox with a QStringList of the QMap's keys.

Eventually get the enum value selected by the user by using the value() method of QMap in combination with the currentText() method of QComboBox.

An example with the **QSerialPort** class and the **QSerialPort::FlowControl** enum :

```
QMap<QString, QSerialPort::FlowControl> *flowControlOptions = new QMap<QString, QSerialPort::FlowControl>;

flowControlOptions->insert("None",QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
flowControlOptions->insert("Software",QSerialPort::SoftwareControl);
flowControlOptions->insert("Hardware",QSerialPort::HardwareControl);

QComboBox *flowControl = new QComboBox;

flowControl->addItems(QStringList(flowControlOptions->keys()));
flowControl->setCurrentIndex(2);

QSerialPort *sPort = new QSerialPort;

// Some code after... The user has selected an option

sPort->setFlowControl(flowControlOptions->value(flowControl->currentText()));
```

Comment: I'm a bigger fan of this approach because the actual enum variable name might be a poor candidate for user display. For example, my variables have underscores, but users don't want no ugly underscores.