# How to address registered Q_ENUM in inherited class?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following class:

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum testEnum
    {
        one= 1,
        two= 2
    };
    Q_ENUM(testEnum)
};
```

And I have a second class which inherits from the first class:

```
 class B : public A
 {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     Q_ENUMS(A::testEnum)
 };
```

If I now include class `B` in a third class and try to use

```
 static int l_enumIdx = B::staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("A::testEnum");
```

it fails! How can I register the `Q_ENUMS` right and access it correctly with `QMetaObject::indexOfEnumerator()`? Or is there a better way to build such structures of enums and register them?

Comment: Hi, can you show us your third class (even if it's really simple). Additionally, please include the error message you're getting – why does it fail. (And btw, [`Q_ENUMS` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691227/what-is-the-difference-between-q-enum-and-q-enums).)

Comment: the third class is quite long and there are really no further information i guess. I have no error message but the function indexOfEnumerator returns -1. So there should be a problem with the Registration. The Function cannot relate to the String "A::testEnum"

Comment: I am curious, what do you use `indexOfEnumerator` for?

Comment: Im trying to build a QComboBox which automatically fills with enums. If i change the enums then the QComboBox automatically adapts and i dont have to fill manually each element.

Comment: it already works, but not with enums of different classes

Comment: basicly this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955918/qt-using-enums-with-qcombobox

Comment: @Chief Your comment: *Im trying to build a QComboBox which automatically fills with enums ...* confirm that you have a XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use `A::` as part of the `indexOfEnumerator()` argument, also from [Qt 5.5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew55.html) you must use Q_ENUM:

```cpp
static int l_enumIdx = B::staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("testEnum");
qDebug()<< l_enumIdx;
```

Output:

```
0
```

Also if you have registered the enum with Q_ENUM in the base class you do not have to do it in the derived class.

---

The enums of the derived class are the same as the base class:

```cpp
qDebug() << (B::testEnum::one == A::testEnum::one);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: But what if i have another "Class C" which also has a enum type called testEnum. If Class B inherits also from Class C and then there would be a conflict ( because in A and C are the same enums). Im trying to reach a structured enums which could have the same names.

Comment: @Chief Create enums with the same name in the base and derived class? What is the meaning of that? What would be the utility? I think you're forcing things. A good practice of programming is not to cause confusion in the code, that is, if you are going to create an enum in the derived class you must be careful not to coincide with any enum in the base class.

Comment: @Chief As you indicate B inherits from A and C, and as you indicate A and C have as enums to testEnum and are registered with Q_ENUM so A and C must inherit from QObject so what you indicate is impossible since a class can not inherit from 2 QObject, Qt does not allow it.

Comment: @Chief I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is your underlying problem.

Comment: it is not confusing. Just think about you have devices which have states and types. Then think about some functions of devices which also have states and types and further more.. and i dont long enum names for all possible ways

Comment: @Chief If the devices have the same states (enums) then I create the base class with those states and inherit from that class, it is not necessary to create the enums returned in the derived classes.

Comment: Okay i guess your right. I was trying to make this to complicated. Now im just using one class where i have longer enums names. Thanks for your help